# Run all Namespace Tasks with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have a namespace with different tasks:

```
namespace :mytest do
  task :setup do; ... end;
  task :task1 do; ... end;
  task :task2 do; ... end;
end
```

When I run *cap mytest* I get *the task `backup' does not exist*.

How do I create a command which calls all tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
task :default do
  setup
  task1
  task2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In one project, I found myself often needing to call all the tasks in a given namespace. Here is a simple monkey patch to the `Namespace` class which will add a `run_all_tasks` method. The method takes an optional `except` array, which should be a list of task names (as symbols) to exclude.

```
module Capistrano
  class Configuration
    module Namespaces
      class Namespace

        def run_all_tasks(except = [])
          except << :all

          self.task_list(false).each do |task|
            task.body.call unless except.include?(task.name)
          end
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

The method will run the tasks in the order they are defined. As with any type of monkey patch\hack, use this method with caution!